# Datatable dont load with Cordova

Tags: php, jquery, cordova, datatable, load

I'm doing a Web App and I want made an .apk, works perfectly, but the datatables doesn't load with Cordova, I tryed it with jsonp, and json, but the datatable don't load, and I'm going crazy

**.js**

```
    $( "#seeUser" ).one( "click", function() {
            $('#tablaUsuarios').DataTable( {
                "ajax":{
                    "dataType" : "jsonp",
                    "jsonpCallback": "hi",
                    "method":"POST",
                    "url":"../php/selectUsers.php"
                },
                "columns":[
                    {"data":"name"},
                    {"data":"type"},
                    {"data":"price"}
                    ],
                    "language": language,
            });
        } );
```

**php**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header("Content-type: application/json"); 
include('Conf/conf.php');
$link = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $conn);

$sent = "SELECT * FROM users";

$result =sqlsrv_query($link, $sent);

if(!$result){
die("Error");
}else{ 
$out=array("data"=>array());
while($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

$output["data"][] = $fila;
$id=$fila["id_usuario"];
$row=array(
    "name"=>$fila["name"],
    "price"=>$fila["price"],
    "type"=>$fila["type"]
);
array_push($out["data"],$row);
}
echo 'hi(' .  json_encode($out) . ')' ;
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);

sqlsrv_close($link);
```

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Comment: We solve it, the problem was the src on the scripts, we have one script imported as <script src="myScript.js"></script> and was called <script src="myscript.js"></script> the problem was the capital letters on Android. Thats why it worked on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solve it, the problem was the src on the scripts, we have one script imported as src="my**S**cript.js"

And was called src="my**s**cript.js" the problem was the **capital letters** on Android. Thats why it worked on Windows. Be caution with that.